# Angular FormControl - click twice to make validation work

Tags: angular, form-control

I'm trying to create my own todo form and it came dowm to validating input of single todo item. Somehow validation doesn't work correctly, it works only if I focus the input, click outside of it, then foucs it once again and then click outside once again. Can somebody, please, explain, me what I'm missing here? I know it's possible to rewrite the code, but would be grateful to understand the reason of such behaviour.

[image]

By commenting out different parts of code, I've reached out that if I delete `(updateTodoChildEvent)="updateTodo($event)"` from `todo-item.component.html` validation works correctly, but I don't know why.

**todo-item.component.ts**

```
import {Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder} from "@angular/forms";
import {Todo} from "../todo";
import {TodoService} from "../todo.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-item',
  templateUrl: './todo-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo-item.component.css']
})
export class TodoItemComponent {
  @Input() todoItemsList: Todo[] = [];
  @Input() todoItem!: Todo;
  @Output() updateTodoEvent = new EventEmitter<Todo>();

  constructor(private todoService: TodoService) {
  }

  updateTodo(todo: Todo) {
    this.updateTodoEvent.emit(todo);
  }
}
```

**todo-item.component.html**

```
<div>
    <form>
      <app-todo-edit
        [todoItemChild]="todoItem"
        (updateTodoChildEvent)="updateTodo($event)"
      >
      </app-todo-edit>
    </form>
</div>
```

**todo-edit.component.ts**

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {Todo} from "../todo";
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-edit',
  templateUrl: './todo-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo-edit.component.css']
})
export class TodoEditComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() updateTodoChildEvent = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() todoItemChild!: Todo;

  formControlChild = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formControlChild.setValue(this.todoItemChild.name);
  }

  onChildInputChange(todo: Todo, val: string) {
    this.updateTodoChildEvent.emit({id: todo.id, name: val});
  }

  getErrorMessage() {
    if (this.formControlChild.hasError('required')) {
      return 'You must enter a value';
    }

    return this.formControlChild.hasError('minlength') ? 'Too short, should be at least 3 symbols' : '';
  }
}
```

**todo-edit.component.html**

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Edit Todo</mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      type="text"
      #inputRef
      (change)="onChildInputChange(todoItemChild, inputRef.value)"
      [formControl]="formControlChild"
    >
    <mat-error *ngIf="formControlChild.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sa9kq7?file=src%2Ftodo-edit%2Ftodo-edit.component.html) However have you considered to use `(input)` instead of `(change)` event? `(input)="onChildInputChange(todoItemChild, inputRef.value)"`

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I propbably made a mistake with further logic in services or something. Input didn't help, but now at least i know abuth this method :-) Will have to provide a whole piece of code to find the solution.